# How to Populate a Web Form to Import Data

Tags: c#, vb.net, csv, web, data-import

all -

I have a website from which I need to daily download specific sets of data using the sites webform to select the criteria for the search; date range, data source, columns, that sort of thing.

Unfortunately, the form resets each time I go to the site and it is very tedious to have to check all those check boxes every morning.

Is there a way to programmatically;

- Bring up the site,
- Log in,
- Select the form,
- Select a date range from date pickers,
- Click a web button to clear the check boxes (the form defaults to all)
- Check specific boxes,
- Click to import the results,
- Save the .csv to a folder,
- Close the site.

I'm guessing this is not really possible, but I thought I'd ask, just in case.

Thanx for any assistance!

Comment: When you say "I have a website..." do you mean it's a website you created? If so, create an API so you can fetch the desired information as JSON, XML, or whatever. If not, ask the site owner if they have an API which you can use.

Comment: You could potentially use some software which is meant for automated user interface testing, and basically write a test script which sets all the values and runs the search. Selenium is one such tool I believe. Or as the comment above says, if this is your site, write an API so that you can then run the search function automatically from a script or scheduled task

Comment: @Andrew Morton: No, it is not my own website; it belongs to a third party from which we are downloading membership data. When I ask about this from the site's support group, I get very cheerful answers that happily and enthusiastically say that my request has been forwarded to the relevant teams.